# Calculating sequential move order from position matrix for Connect4 puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, puzzle

I wanted to know weather we can calculate the move order such that if the order of the element is played out sequentially we get the current position on board.

example:

this is the current position of the board:
[board position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6TyC.png)

we know the coordinates of the coins from this picture, :

- row 1  col 3 = yellow
- row 1  col 4 = red
- row 1  col 5 = yellow
- row 2  col 3 = red
- row 2  col 5 = red
- row 3  col 5 = yellow

in this scenario, the move order (columns) played was : **4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5** (red and yellow alternates, the numbers represent which columns the coin was dropped, ie, the first coin(red) was dropped on the 4th row, second coin(yellow) was dropped on 3rd row, third coin(red) was dropped again on 3rd row... )

I wanted to know weather we can reconstruct the move order from the position matrix (*the move order need not be the exact order played, but if we were to simulate, the resulting position matrix should be the same*)

Comment: What do you mean by "the position matrix"?

Comment: There are exactly two sequences of moves that could have led to this position. You have given one. The other is $4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5$

Comment: @PaulSinclair , position matrix is the matrix denoting the coins location red = [ (1,4) , (2,3) , (2,5) ] yellow = [ (1,3), (1,5), (3,5) ] (y,x cordinates ) based on image i have added.

Comment: That does not describe a "matrix" as we use the term in Math. But apparently you just mean the game position. So the answer is yes, you can deduce the moves that resulted in that position, up to two possible choices - The one you gave, or the one I gave. However, that is a property of this particular position. Other positions may be reachable by many more paths.

Answer (score 1):

To see that there are only two paths that lead to the position
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\color{yellow}\bullet&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\color{red}\bullet&\cdot&\color{red}\bullet&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\color{yellow}\bullet&\color{red}\bullet&\color{yellow}\bullet&\cdot&\cdot
\end{array}$$
Note that the first play must be on the bottom, since coins can only rest on the bottom or on other coins.

- Since Red moved first, they must have moved on column 4, since that is the only red coin on the bottom.
- There is no Yellow on Red's first coin, so Yellow's first move was a different column. It could be either the coin in column 3 or the coin in column 5.
- As Red has no other coins on the bottom, their second move was to a column already played. But there is no Red coin on top of Red's first coin, so the column of Red's second move was the same as Yellow's first.
- If Yellow started out playing column 3, then they must have played column 5 next, as both of their other coins are in that column. But if Yellow played 5 first, their other coins are in 3 and 5. It would appear that Yellow could have made either choice now, but if Yellow were to play 5 twice before playing 3, this would prevent Red from making their final move. So Yellow must play the other column of 3 or 5 than they played the first time.
- Red's third play must be in the other of columns 3 or 5 than they played in their second round. But their coin is on a Yellow coin, so Yellow had to have played that column on their second turn.
- Yellow's final move must be the remaining column 5 coin.

Thus if Yellow choose column 3 on their first turn, the sequence of moves must be the one you gave: $4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5$. If Yellow chose column 5 on their first turn, the sequence of moves must be the one I gave: $4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5$.